# changing button location on panel,Group box or Table layout panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I simply want to swap two buttons on a window form , it is OK but when I put buttons on a `Panel`,`GroupBox` or `TableLayoutPanel` nothing happens.
I tried code snippet below for swapping:

```
 System.Drawing.Point locationTemp = button2.Location;
       button2.Location = button1.Location;
       button1.Location = locationTemp;
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's unclear if these buttons are in the same container.  The TableLayoutPanel only allows one control per cell.  So, which parent container has these buttons?  Or is it a mix?

Comment: @LarsTech , any cell contains just one button and I have 9 buttons on the form.

Comment: So this is a TableLayoutPanel that is housing these buttons?  It matters because that panel is much different than an ordinary Panel or GroupBox.

Comment: @LarsTech , I tried all of them (Panel,GroupBox,TableLayoutPanel) to see if problem is solved but no different was made .

Comment: Your code works (except for TableLayoutPanel, which would use `SetCellPosition(...)`).  Any Dock properties, etc?

Comment: @LarsTech ,would you explain it as a answer? i just need to swap two buttons in any click ( buttons housed on a TableLayoutPanel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works unless these controls are in a TableLayoutPanel, which behaves differently since child controls are members of a cell (only one parent control allowed per cell):

```
TableLayoutPanelCellPosition cell1 = tlp.GetCellPosition(button1);
tlp.SetCellPosition(button1, tlp.GetCellPosition(button2));
tlp.SetCellPosition(button2, cell1);
```